# How to perform periodic tasks within Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a web app on Django platform.

I have a method within views.py:

```
def task():
    print("my task")
```

how can I run it every day once?

I need a very simple solution and it should be independent of other tasks (parallel).

Comment: Is this function registered as a view in `urls.py` or is it just a normal python function? If the later, then it should be in a different file.

Comment: Try using `django-celery-beat` [link](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat)

Comment: not registered in urls

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries that help facilitate periodic tasks. Two that I have used are [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) and [django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Celery is a general python task manager. Using it with django requires additional libraries to bring them together. Where as django-q is specifically for django projects.

On a side note, if the `task()` function is not an actual view, then it belongs in a separate file other than `views.py`.

Comment: is there another simpler solution? Celery is too complex for a simple task

Comment: django-q. it doesn't get any simpler

Comment: @NasimiEldarov Django-Q is less complex than celery in my experience, but I find it's documentation less robust, especially in the introduction/overview area. As an aside, the complexity of the task is entirely independent of the complexity of scheduling it to run.